# Quarter circle shape with a container in flutter

Tags: containers, flutter, shapes, geometry

I want to have a container with a quarter circle shape, think of a quarter slice of a whole pizza.

How do I achieve this? Basically I want to place it on top of another container in the lower right location with the round part facing inward and the angle of course matching where the lower right corner form the bottom container is, using a stack widget.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `CustomPainter` combined with `ClipRect` to draw a circle and crop it.

[image]

```
enum CircleAlignment {
  topLeft,
  topRight,
  bottomLeft,
  bottomRight,
}

class QuarterCircle extends StatelessWidget {
  final CircleAlignment circleAlignment;
  final Color color;

  const QuarterCircle({
    this.color = Colors.grey,
    this.circleAlignment = CircleAlignment.topLeft,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.expand(
      child: ClipRect(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: QuarterCirclePainter(
            circleAlignment: circleAlignment,
            color: color,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuarterCirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final CircleAlignment circleAlignment;
  final Color color;

  const QuarterCirclePainter({this.circleAlignment, this.color});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final radius = math.min(size.height, size.width);
    final offset = circleAlignment == CircleAlignment.topLeft
        ? Offset(.0, .0)
        : circleAlignment == CircleAlignment.topRight
            ? Offset(size.width, .0)
            : circleAlignment == CircleAlignment.bottomLeft
                ? Offset(.0, size.height)
                : Offset(size.width, size.height);
    canvas.drawCircle(offset, radius, Paint()..color = color);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(QuarterCirclePainter oldDelegate) {
    return color == oldDelegate.color &&
        circleAlignment == oldDelegate.circleAlignment;
  }
}
```

which you can use by doing

```
QuarterCircle(
  circleAlignment: CircleAlignment.bottomLeft,
),
```

Comment: Tested it out in the default flutter create app, but I don't see it show up anywhere, am I missing something? I placed it on both the Column and directly as the scaffold body.

Comment: You need to give it a size. It won't magically know which size you want. Wrap it into a SizedBox or anything else

Comment: Now it worked, please edit post with implementation using a wrapper and I will mark as accepted answer. And thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: Below your "which you can use by doing" comment, wrap the QuarterCircle in your suggested SizedBox.

Comment: Might as well force it to expand. Done

Answer (score 4):

It will be very easy to use `Container` for creating Quarter-circle. Just create a `Container` with **equal height and width**. Use  `borderRadius: BorderRadius.only()` property and set radius for any one side with **same height**

Sample code :

```
 Container(
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.black,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: That's enough. Good Job.