# how to make custom container like this:

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, data-structures, mvvm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLNsJ.png)
I need to make this custom container

I tried more to make it by border radius but I can not do it and I wish stack over flow do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51690662/14360762

Answer (score 0):

You can set the border radius for each corner using DecoratedBox:

```
Center(
    child: DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent.shade200,
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(4),
      topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
      topRight: Radius.circular(8),
      ),
      ),
      child: const SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      ),
    ),
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```dart
Container(
  height: 100.0,
  width: 100.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.orange[100],
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
      topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100.0),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
    ),
  ),
),
```